# jQuery: fade images below a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I have a background image for a link that I would like to fade and rotate.  I use two divs, one with the image, and one that's blank white.  On top of those is a linked image.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/YURg8/48/

The link is not active while fading in Chrome or FF, but works in IE.

Suggestions?

Comment: I guess you mean "works" and not "active". I use Firefox and it works. Are you confident about what you're saying?

Comment: Doesn't work until the end of the animation for me, FF 12.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an element to wrap those `div`-s and position them absolute - http://jsfiddle.net/YURg8/49/

```
wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#bgblack {
    background:#555;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}

#bgwhite {
    background:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}

#link {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: yellowgreen;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```